# Heroku: django syncdb doesn't seem to do anything.

Tags: django, heroku, django-syncdb

I pushed my app to heroku  after making sure it works fine in my local environment.

When I try to sync db using:

```
    heroku run myapp/manage.py syncdb
```

I see just this. No tables are created.

```
    Running myapp/manage.py syncdb attached to terminal... up, run.1
```

And my app fails when it tries to access the db with this error.

```
    Exception Type: DatabaseError at /oauth_callback/
    Exception Value: relation "django_session" does not exist
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I have no experience with Heroku but the docs do contain an example that differs from the one you're entering: `heroku run _python_ myapp/manage.py syncdb`.

Comment: Thanks that worked.
`heroku run python myapp/manage.py syncdb`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me. Thanks Roam: 
`heroku run _python_ myapp/manage.py syncdb`

Comment: This didn't work for me, however `heroku run python manage.py syncdb` did. Thanks!